Clickhouse WindowFunnel Average Time
I have a WindowFunnel query to analyze event sequence:
SELECT
        level,
        count() as result

        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                mid,
                windowFunnel(6048000000000000, 'strict_order')(creation_time, event='cs52', event='21fa') AS level
            from clickhouse_analytics_local as event_table where

        creation_time >= '2024-04-15 00:00:00' AND creation_time <= '2024-04-15 23:59:59' AND
        event IN ['cs52', '21fa', '5x6o']

            GROUP BY mid
        )

        GROUP BY level
        ORDER BY level ASC;

i want to get average elapsed time between each level in clickhouse window funnel
